# switch statement assign to NSlocalizedString

Tags: iphone, swift, switch-statement, case

How can I assign `updateHeaderNotifications` and DebugAlert to `NSlocalizedString`? I tried to add `updateHeaderNotifications = Nslocalized("text_text")` but it doesnt work. Thanks for help

```
private func initViewToCurrentState(pocketStatus: pocketStatus?) {
    if let status = pocketStatus {
        switch status {
        case .Created:
            **updateHeaderNotifications** ("text1")
            initpocketBeforeTripView()

        case .Paid: fallthrough
        case .Undone: fallthrough
        case .Aborted: fallthrough
        default:
            PocketRideService.sharedInstance.removeCachedRide()
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
                DebugAlert.show("text")

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How updateHeaderNotifications is defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your method definition, you can use like below:

```
private func updateHeaderNotifications(bigNotify: String, smallNotify: String) {
    bigNotification.text = NSLocalizedString(bigNotify, comment: "bigNotify")//you can set any text for comment parameter
    smallNotification.text = NSLocalizedString(smallNotify, comment: "smallNotify")
}
```

and in your `switch` statement:

```
        case .Created:
        updateHeaderNotifications("text1", smallNotify: "text2")
```

Comment: can i do like that ?

Comment: case .Created:
                updateHeaderNotifications(NSLocalizedString("AA_AA"), NSLocalizedString("AA_AA2"))
                initRouteBeforeTripView())

Comment: `NSLocalizedString`, requires two parameters. Yes, you can try to set your text in switch itself.